# Cómo cargar un arreglo de imágenes desde Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Hola soy nuevo en Flutter, quiero una página que cargue un arreglo de imágenes desde firebase pero solo carga una imagen en un arreglo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productsRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("banners");

  Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: _productsRef.get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map<Widget>((document) {
                    return Image.network("${document['images'][0]}");
                  }).toList(growable: true)
              );
            }
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],

    );
  }

}
```

Visualización de una sola imagen
[image: Visualización de una sola imagen]

BD Firebase:
[image: base de datos de firebase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en el `children` del `ListView` solo estás pasándole un objeto que contiene un array de elementos. Deberías pasarle el array directamente.

En lugar de :

```dart
return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map<Widget>((document) {
                    return Image.network("${document['images'][0]}");
                  }).toList(growable: true)
              );
```

Podrías hacer:

```dart
return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs[0]['images'].map<Widget>((image) {
                    return Image.network(image);
                  }).toList(growable: true)
              );
```

Con ese cambio, lo que haces es traer el primer documento(según tu imagen, tienes solo uno), y luego extraes el campo `images` que es un array de Strings, sobre eso haces el map para convertirlo a widget de Image.

Comment: Hola, una duda adicional, ¿es posible asignarle una url personalizada a cada imagen?, para que el usuario al momento de hacerle un tap a la imagen lo redirija a un sitio o archivo en específico